# Is it possible to record video from webcam to file using Xuggle Xuggler only?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, webcam, video-capture

I have tried last 2 weeks to record from webcam to file, but I have been unable to get Webcam Capture API working on my Raspberry Pi model B+.

Application starts, but it freezes at the end without any console errors.

[Java source code](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-video-recording/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/webcam/Encoder.java) which record from webcam, but freezes at the end and leaves 100% CPU usage until terminated with ctrl+c.

Xuggle Xuggler seems to work fine, but is it even possible to record video using Xuggle Xuggler only?

I have found demos for Xuggle Xuggler, but none of these record file from webcam

[Xuggle Xuggler java demos](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos)

So is it possible to record video using xuggle xuggler and java libraries or is it just again a waste of time?

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that it wasn't just waste of time...

Source code below will capture video to file using only Xuggle Xuggler and Java libraries. Source code will work when using only resolution 320x240 or above that is because xuggle xugglers [lousy webcam support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758781/5510077).

I'm still waiting better and faster solution for my orginal problem to be accepted as answer.

```
package webcam;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IError;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IMetaData;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoResampler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Utils;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.ConverterFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.IConverter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;


public class Uusi {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        File file = new File("output.h264");
        IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());

        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, 320, 240);

        String driverName = "vfwcap";
        String deviceName = "0";

        // Let's make sure that we can actually convert video pixel formats.
        if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work");
        }

        // Create a Xuggler container object
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();

        // Tell Xuggler about the device format
        IContainerFormat format = IContainerFormat.make();
        if (format.setInputFormat(driverName) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("couldn't open webcam device: " + driverName);
        }

        // devices, unlike most files, need to have parameters set in order
        // for Xuggler to know how to configure them, for a webcam, these
        // parameters make sense
        IMetaData params = IMetaData.make();

        params.setValue("framerate", "30/1");
        params.setValue("video_size", "320x240");


        // Open up the container
        int retval = container.open(deviceName, IContainer.Type.READ, format,
                false, true, params, null);
        if (retval < 0) {
            // This little trick converts the non friendly integer return value into
            // a slightly more friendly object to get a human-readable error name
            IError error = IError.make(retval);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + deviceName + "; Error: " + error.getDescription());
        }

        // query how many streams the call to open found
        int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

        // and iterate through the streams to find the first video stream
        int videoStreamId = -1;
        IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) {
            // Find the stream object
            IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
            // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
            IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

            if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                videoStreamId = i;
                videoCoder = coder;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoStreamId == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not find video stream in container: " + deviceName);
        }

        /*
         * Now we have found the video stream in this file.  Let's open up our decoder so it can
         * do work.
         */
        if (videoCoder.open() < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not open video decoder for container: " + deviceName);
        }

        IVideoResampler resampler = null;
        if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
            // if this stream is not in BGR24, we're going to need to
            // convert it.  The VideoResampler does that for us.
            resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
                    videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());
            if (resampler == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("could not create color space resampler for: " + deviceName);
            }
        }


        /*
         * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet.
         */
        IPacket packet = IPacket.make();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int i = 0;
        while (container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0 && i < 100) {
            /*
             * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our video stream
             */
            if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId) {
                /*
                 * We allocate a new picture to get the data out of Xuggler
                 */
                IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
                        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

                int offset = 0;
                while (offset < packet.getSize()) {
                    /*
                     * Now, we decode the video, checking for any errors.
                     * 
                     */
                    int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, offset);
                    if (bytesDecoded < 0) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding video in: " + deviceName);
                    }
                    offset += bytesDecoded;

                    /*
                     * Some decoders will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
                     * a full video picture yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
                     * got a complete picture from the decoder
                     */
                    if (picture.isComplete()) {
                        IVideoPicture newPic = picture;
                        /*
                         * If the resampler is not null, that means we didn't get the video in BGR24 format and
                         * need to convert it into BGR24 format.
                         */
                        if (resampler != null) {
                            // we must resample
                            newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
                            if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("could not resample video from: " + deviceName);
                            }
                        }
                        if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " + deviceName);
                        }

                        // Convert the BGR24 to an Java buffered image
                        BufferedImage javaImage = Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic);   

                        System.out.println("Capture frame " + i);

                        BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(javaImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                        IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

                        IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
                        frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
                        frame.setQuality(0);

                        writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);          

                        i++;
                    }

                }

            } else {
                /*
                 * This packet isn't part of our video stream, so we just silently drop it.
                 */
                do {
                } while (false);
            }

        }

        writer.close();

        System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** When testing above code on Raspberry Pi Model B+, it records the video, but when watching the recorded video it seems to be in "fast-fordward"-mode. So code is not good, because raspberry takes much more time when encoding video than powerful laptop (Windows 8.1).